# Name of a Teen Sci-fi series

Tags: story-identification

I read a teen Sci-fi series when I was in junior high (early 90’s) about an international space training school.  Brilliant teens from all over the world were selected to compete in teams for top ranks.  I believe that they were going to terraform Mars.  This maybe took place in a space station, and was NOT Enders Game.  I think that there were maybe four of them.  Help!

Comment: It probably *isn't* this one, so I won't make it an "Answer," but are you familiar with *The Princes of Earth* by Michael Kurland? A YA SF novel which starts with the narrator, a teenage boy on a backwater planet, aceing a stringent qualification test and winning a full scholarship to possibly the most elite school in the Empire -- The University of Sol on Mars. Which is ironic, because he was *only hoping* to do well enough to get into a good university right there on his homeworld! (I hear it was meant to be the start of a series, but somehow Kurland never wrote any sequels.)

Comment: Sounds like you read a novelisation of [Space Camp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpaceCamp) ...? No Mars, but four teens, and they end up on a space station.